# Show UIActionSheetUser if does not allow UIImagePickerController to access photo library

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimagepickercontroller, photo, photolibrary

Is there a way to get notified when I want to show a UIImagePickerController but the user does not allow my app to access the photo library.

Or can I somehow get the information if the user said yes or no when they get presented the popup if they want allow this app to access the photo library.

So I can show a UIActionSheet to inform the user what I am going to do with the picture?

Answer (score 2):

You can save the answer into NSUserDefaults and then later gather this info to choose what should be presented to the user.

Comment: But how do I get the answer?

Comment: From UIAlertView for example.

Comment: I am not getting it. The AlertView where the user can choose yes or now is presented by the system not by me. so how would I get what he selected?